# Jquery listview is not updated

Tags: jquery, listview

Hi I have problems with updating my lists when jumping between sections in my html page.
This is just a formating problem I guess because all the rows is presented right so the xml read is right.
I think that It might be a refresh problem for the list.
If I use this row with refresh nothing will happen and the xml will not be parsed to begin with.:

```
    $('#lists' + nextPage).listview("refresh")
```

If I use this row with trigger() and without listview with refresh, the list will still not be formated right but the xml will be parsed and put in the page.

```
    $('#lists' + nextPage).append("<li>"+rows+"</li>").trigger('create')
```

Here is a short bit from my javascript:

```
    $(xml).find('swedish').each(function() {
        $(this).find('site[id="' + pageNum + '"]').each(function() {
            $(this).find('quiz').each(function() {
                $('#lists' + nextPage).text(''),
                $(this).find('row').each(function() {
                    rows = $(this).text(),
                    $('#lists' + nextPage).append("<li>"+rows+"</li>").trigger('create')
                    //$('#lists' + nextPage).listview("refresh")
                }); //each
            }); //each
        }); //each
    }); //within success function
    $.mobile.changePage("#page" + nextPage, {
        transition: "slide",
        reverse: false
    })
```

Here is a short bit from my html:

```
    <section id="page1" data-role="page">
        <header data-role="header" id="quiz">
            <table border="0" align="center">
                <tr align="center">
                    <td align="right"><h3>Quiz</h3></td>
                    <td align="left"><div id="pagecounter1">
                            <h3>0</h3>
                        </div></td></tr
                ></table>
        </header>

        <ul id="lists1" data-role="listview">
        </ul>
    </section>
```

I want it to be formated like if you make a list view with: "data-role="listview"
You can see in the code that I'm doing just that but it looks like a unformat list like this:

```
    item1
    item2
    item2
    ...
```

Comment: Hehehe...sorry I'm from Sweden and that means the Swedish language.
I'm collecting a couple quizes in Swedish from the xml:)

Comment: I'm really trying to get the right format in this list.
Am I calling this from the wrong place in the script?:
        $('#lists' + nextPage).listview("refresh")

Comment: Maybe I want to do something like this:

      $('#lists' + nextPage).append("<ul data-role=" + "'listview'" + "><li>"+rows+"</li></ul>").trigger('create')

I know this looks wrong but please correct me:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var list = "<ul data-role=" + "'listview'" + "><li>"+rows+"</li></ul>";
$('your list container selector').append(list).listview().trigger('create');
```

Comment: This almost solved my problem and my list is generated with a error catched with my try/catch clause....Thanks:)
New error:
TypeError: Result of expression 'c[0]' [undefined] is not an object